# Re-enable VSTO add-in that is disabled by the Application due to multiple errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto, excel-2010

I am writing and debugging an Excel VSTO Ribbon addin and it sometimes crashes due to errors in code. When Excel finally decides it's too much and asked me whether I want to permanantly disable it, I ACCIDENTALLY clicked yes.

Now no matter what I do, I cannot get the addin to automatically load on Excel startup. I go to COMs AddIn dialog and set the checkbox; deleted the registry settings manually; cleaned the project in Visual Studio and rebuilt it -- no use.

Where should I configure to make it auto load my VSTO again? Thanks in advance. btw, it's Excel 2010 on my dev machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have made the addin disabled. To enable it back

Select File => Options then choose Add-Ins.
In the Manage dropdown choose Disabled items and if your addin is listed there just enable it.

Comment: \*pulls hair\* I don't know why I missed the "disabled items" I was looking at COMs Add-In and the check box just never stays.