# VSTO Excel addin doesn't work

Tags: c#, vsto

I have created a VSTO Excel addin(myAddin) using C#.net.I have the Excel Addin( myAddin) loaded in excel -> addins menu and works fine in my machine.

I have shared the Setup file and installer package file to Users.
For some users it runs the code after selecting the addin and works fine without any issues.
For some users after selecting the addin it does nothing.It even didnt raise any exception.

When i added logs to the code i realized its not calling the Addin_startup() event .

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What a wonderful question! Are there any error messages?

Comment: it didnt raise any exception.Is there a way we can find out the info abt the same from event logs.

Comment: To provide you more information when the addin is selected then a windows form will be loaded.When user clicks on the button on thsi form "Submit" a method  CreateWorkITems () from the ThisAddin.cs file will be called.When this method is called it automatically calls ThisAddIn_Startup().This call didnt happen to the users where it failed to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this tips](http://exceptionalcode.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/vsto-troubleshooting-quick-tips/) for VSTO troubleshooting.

Also see whether your addin is disabled. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752455/re-enable-vsto-add-in-that-is-disabled-by-the-application-due-to-multiple-errors/10757919#10757919) to enable your addin

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but i had a similar problem. and the reason was i was installing a 32 bit installer on 64 Bit office .
you need to put registry keys for 64 bit office separately.
check the below link. may be it would help.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx